# Why does create-react-app build my app with the debug version of Dashjs?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, dash.js

I have a React app using the [Dashjs player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dashjs). I build it with `react-scripts build` and the app works fine except that it uses `dash.all.debug.js` instead of `dash.all.min.js`.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like [dashjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dashjs) module is exporting the debug file as their main file program:

after running `npm install dashjs@4.0.0-npm`, i opened `./node_modules/dashjs/package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "dashjs",
  "version": "4.0.0-npm",
  "description": "A reference client implementation for the playback of MPEG DASH via Javascript and compliant browsers.",
  "author": "Dash Industry Forum",
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "main": "dist/dash.all.debug.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

as you can see, `"main": "dist/dash.all.debug.js"` is declared as the main entry point

when you import the package:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dashjs from 'dashjs';

export default class App extends Component { ... }
```

the debug version will be bundled in your final artifact

to change that, you can explicit import the min version:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dashjs from 'dashjs/dist/dash.all.min.js';

export default class App extends Component { ... }
```

or open an issue in dashjs repository

Comment: Thanks! The explicit import did the trick. And I also posted something on the Dashjs github for good measure.